# How to prove with given conditions that $\mathcal{T}_2$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_1$ i.e. $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set with $\mathcal{T}_1, \mathcal{T}_2$ topologies on $X$, let $\mathcal{B}_1$ be a basis for $\mathcal{T}_1$ and let $\mathcal{B}_2$ be a basis for $\mathcal{T}_2$.
Now let for all $x \in X$ and all $U_1 \in \mathcal{B}_1$ with $x \in U_1$, exist a $U_2 \in \mathcal{B}_2$ with $x \in U_2$ and $U_2 \subseteq U_1$.

With all this given I want to proof that $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$.

I have actually no idea where to start I hope somebody can help me out with this question.

I also have to proof why from this it follows that the product topology on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ is equal to the euclidian topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 0):

An open set is a union of basis elements. Now take an open $U\in\mathcal T_1$, write it as a union of $U_i\in \mathcal B_1$, then use the condition to write each $U_i$ as a union of $V_j\in\mathcal B_2$, and you're done, since $U$ is the union of all the $V_j$.

---

**Edit:** How to write a given $U_i \in \mathcal B_1$ as a union of $V_j \in \mathcal B_2$.

For every $x \in U_i$, let $V_x \in \mathcal B_2$ be a neighbourhood of $x$ of the kind that is given by our condition (i.e. we have $x \in V_x \subseteq U_i$). This gives
$$
U_i = \bigcup_{x \in U_i}\{x\} \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in U_i}V_x \subseteq U_i
$$
which means that the inclusions above are all equalities (the first inclusion is because $\{x\}\subseteq V_x$, and the second equality is because $V_x \subseteq U_i$ is true for all $x$, therefore their union must also be contained in $U_i$). This means that we have written $U_i$ as a union of elements from $\mathcal B_2$.

Note that while I used $i$ and $j$ as indices, there is no guarantee that the index set can be taken as finite, or even countable.

Comment: I don't see how I could use the condition to write each $U_i$ as a union of $V_j \in \mathcal{B}_2$.

Comment: @TheTriforce I added some details. Please take a look.